# Forced Downcasting in Java

Tags: java, class, object, casting, downcast

I want to force a downcast on a object what can't be down casted and was wondering what the right approach would be.
The use case is that I have a list of rules that are checked and what will generate a list of failed rule. A failed rule is a subclass of a rule. But downcasting like
    *FailedRule failedRule = (FailedRule) rule;*

will fail because the rule object is not an instanceof FailedRule

To work around this I instantiate a clone;
    *FailedRule failedRule =  new FailedRule (rule);*

and my FailedRule class looks like this

```
public class FailedRule extends Rule{

/* 
 *force a down cast from Rule to FailedRule through cloning
*/
public FailedRule (Rule upcast){
   super.setRuleCode( upcast.getRuleCode());
   super.setType(upcast.getType());
   ..
```

Is there a easier way to do this?
To answer myself, the design is flawed, the code should be:

```
public class FailedRule{
  private Rule rule;
  ..
  public setRule(Rule rule){
  ..
```

Comment: I'm wondering how you end up having to _force downcast on an object that can't be down casted_. Explain us what you really wanna do.

Comment: I though I did :-). I loop through a list of rules and return a list of rules that have failed. The checking process returns a fair amount of information per rule why and when and how it has failed. Mark's answer is correct, my design is wrong, I can't say that a failed rule 'is a' rule. It 'has a' rule. I've edited the question because I can't put code in these comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a symptom that your inheritance hierarchy is weakly designed.  You're trying to introduce mutability of attributes through inheritance (a `Rule` has "failed" if it is an instance-of `FailedRule`).  Inheritance isn't really good for that sort of thing.

I would say you should either use composition (a FailedRule has a Rule as a source) or that `failed` should be a boolean attribute of an instance of `Rule`.

Comment: Ok, so FailedRule is not a subclass of a rule because a failed rule is not a rule. A FailedRule class is a failed rule that has a rule as a property; failedRule.setRule(rule); failedRule.setReason(reason) etc.

Comment: @Meindert:  I'm not sure if that's a good approach or not, since I don't have much context.  What extra aspects does `FailedRule` even provide?  *What changes about the internal state of a rule now that it has failed?*  If it were me, I would say "a rule failed if it appears in the list of failed rules."  It seems logical to separate the concept of the rule from the results of its execution.  Just like you wouldn't store the place a Car scored in its last race in the Car itself; you'd have a `RaceRecord` that references the car.

Comment: If composition is the way to go, I would consider renaming `FailedRule`.  It is-not-a rule, is it?  It's just a context/record of a rule failing.  I would call it `RuleFailure` or something similar instead.

Comment: Well, in the eye of the user, it is a list of rules that are failed... But you are right I store the failed rules in a table called RuleFail.

Answer (score 2):

Use a method that converts any rule to a `FailedRule`:

```
public static FailedRule asFailedRule(Rule rule){
    return (rule instanceof FailedRule)
    ? (FailedRule) rule
    : new FailedRule(rule)
}
```

(If the rule is already a `FailedRule`, cast and return it, otherwise use it to construct a `FailedRule`)

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks like a reasonable solution. If any rule could potentially be a failed rule, it might be more appropriate to model that as `Rule.isFailed()`.

**Edit:** *Failed* sounds very much like a state, not a variant of a rule. If that is the case `Rule.isFailed()` would also be to prefer. If there are rules that really don't fail, we could model that as:

```
           Rule
         /      \
         |       \
    FailableRule  RuleC
     /     |   
 RuleA    RuleB
```

Hmm... is a *failable* rule actually a *fallible* rule? Gaawgh... linguistics.

Comment: This is a good idea, even if the method only contains `return false;` on `Rule` and is overridden in `FailedRule` to `return true;`.

Comment: Actually just thought of another thing. *Failed* sounds very much like a state of a rule, not a variant of a rule. If that is the case, `FailedRule` is not great oo.

Comment: The question, though, is about downcasting, not evaluating his design choices.

Comment: Don't agree for a second there. A very large proportion of the questions that come into SO are clearly about people not understanding the technology or the problem they're dealing with. If I see glaring omissions or problematic thinking, I will obviously try to help with the whole picture, despite the question being about a specific thing beside the point. This a reason why users should give as much context as possible.

Comment: The user who submitted this question is probably never going to come back and look at it.  Most people who come here will be searching for downcasting.  So, we should focus on answering the question, not evaluating the experience of the user who hasn't bothered to come back and clarify.

Comment: Hee, I do come back! :-) And I do think that giving an answer to the underlying issue is more helpfull than the short answer that there isn't a easy way to force a down cast. I changed my code because what I took from this is that a failed rule is not a type of rule but is a failed rule that has a rule as a property; My failed rule has a few other properties like; when, by who and what has failed the rule

Answer (score 0):

**There is no easier way.  You are doing this correctly.**

Many times, I will write a private method, something like this:

```
private void copyFromRule(Rule otherRule) {
  this.setRuleCode(otherRule.getRuleCode());
  this.setType(otherRule.getType());
  ...
}
```

This way, I can call it in a constructor like this, and also in a `clone()` method if I need to define one.

Another point is to know if you're calling `super.setRuleCode` or `this.setRuleCode`.  Obviously, these two things do different things depending on if `FailedRule` redefines `setRuleCode`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a class to a subclass like that.  It doesn't make sense as it wouldn't have any of the methods or variables from the subclass.  The way you're doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is correct. The only comment I have to add is to move the copy code down to Rule itself.

```
public class FailedRule extends Rule{

/* 
 *force a down cast from Rule to FailedRule through cloning
*/
public FailedRule (Rule upcast){
   super(upcast);
   //init FailedRule fields to defaults
}
}

public class Rule {

publiic Rule(Rule ruleToCopy) {
   //or even use the fields themselves. 
   this.setRuleCode( ruleToCopy.getRuleCode());
   this.setType(ruleToCopy.getType());
   ...
```

Comment: thanks, that is a cleaner way of cloning. I was looking for a 'auto cloning' methode that would place all the properties of ruleToCopy into 'this'. But I go with the answer from mark that my design is flawed